# Android ListView with multiple onclick listener and GestureDetector

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using GestureDetector for first time on list view. It works fine for me till i have multiple onclick on ListView item. I want GestureDetector for whole list but its not working where i have onclick event for some part of item in ListView.

Consider my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineraMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/meet_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="#ef3d4a"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/note"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="#ef3d4a"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/note"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_delete_red"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For textid and meet_time of TextView i set onclicklistener, When i try to swipe on this text it does not work. For GestureDetector i have extended SimpleOnGestureListener.

Please give me suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to understand how `OnTouch` events work.
First thing first, `OnClickListener` is a private case of `OnTouchListenter` and what it does is listen to `down` and `up` touch events on a certain view. If a touch event is "handled" by a certain listener, that listener returns **true** which stops the event propagating to more "general" views that cover/contain it.
In your case what happens is that the `OnClickListener` handles the event and does not let the `ListView` to get the touch event. <s>You potentially could implement your own `OnClickListener` which only differs from the standard one by that it returns `false` for clicks it detects.</s>
You should extent your `ListView` and implement `onInterceptTouchEvent` this will allow the `ListView` to "see" the touch event (which you could run through your `GestureDetector` and handle accordingly)

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //run through your GestureDetector
        if (ev.getActionMasked() != ACTION_DOWN && yourGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
        {
            //you have detected your gesture
            //....
        }
        return false; //return false so that the child TextViews will continue to get touch events
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would you please give me example?

Comment: check out my edited answer, I think you'll have your answer now